# How do I define a datatype to be an int in a structure without redefining my class type in a class object?

Tags: c++

I am having difficulty resolving a redefinition error. Basically, I have a class object called houseClassType in my class header file and I also have to use houseClassType as my datatype for an array within my structure in my struct header file. Below are the two header files:

house header file:

```
#include "Standards.h"

#ifndef house_h
#define house_h

//Definition of class, house
class houseClassType
{
    //Data declaration section
private:
    int capacityOfGarage;
    int yearBuilt;
    int listingNumber;

    double price;
    double taxes;
    double roomCounts[3];

    string location;
    string style;

    //Private method to set the county name
    string SetCountyName(string);
    string SetSchoolDistrictName(string);

    //Private method to set school district name
    void SetSchoolDistrictName(void);

    //Set function for the object 
    void ExtractLocationData(string& state, string& county, string& city,
    string& schoolDistrictName, string& address);

    //Methods declaration
public:

    ///Default Constructor 
    houseClassType(void);

    ///Get methods for data members - INLINE
    int GetCapacity(void) { return capacityOfGarage; };
    int GetYearBuilt(void) { return yearBuilt; };
    int GetListingNumber(void) { return listingNumber; };

    double GetPrice(void) { return price; };
    double GetTaxes(void) { return taxes; };

    string GetLocation(void) { return location; };
    string GetStyle(void) { return style; };

    void GetRoomCounts(double[]);

    //Set methods for data members
    void SetCapacityOfGarage(int);
    void SetYearBuilt(int);
    void SetListingNumber(int);

    void SetPrice(double);
    void SetTaxes(double);

    void SetLocation(string);
    void SetStyle(string);

    void SetRoomCounts(double[]);

    //Output methods for data members
    void OutputLocationData(ofstream&);
    void OutputStyle(ofstream&);
    void OutputRoomCounts(ofstream&);
    void OutputCapacityOfGarage(ofstream&);
    void OutputYearBuilt(ofstream&);
    void OutputPrice(ofstream&);
    void OutputTaxes(ofstream&);
    void OutputListingNumber(ofstream&);
    void OutputHouse(ofstream&);

    ///Destructor
    ~houseClassType(void);

};

#endif
```

Realtor header file:

```
#include "Standards.h"

#ifndef Realtor_h
#define Realtor_h

const int NUMBER_OF_HOMES = 30;

typedef int houseClassType;

struct realtorStructType
{
    string agentName;


    houseClassType homes[NUMBER_OF_HOMES];  ///Redefinition error here


    int numberOfHomes;
};

void InputHomes(ifstream& fin, string agentName, int& numberOfHomes);


#endif
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you should reduce the code to a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) From all those lines of code, only 3-4 are relevant to your question.

Comment: Why do you need to use the same name `houseClassType` for the typedef? Anyway, if you want to have different types with the same names, you need to use namespaces.

Comment: @Barmar You're correct, it doesn't have to be a typedef. But could you give me an example of what you call "use namespaces" to resolve this?

Comment: It's like when you do `using namespace std;` to use the `std` namespace.

Comment: Or when you write `std::cin` to access `cin` in the `std` namespace.

Comment: I cant see any good reason why 2 completely diffirent things should have the same name. Its an open invitation for errors.

Comment: In your `realtorStructType`, do you want an array of integers or an array of `houseClassType`?  That `typedef` is the root of your issues.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews An array of houseClassType! Since it is for this type of array, what changes would be necessary? Thank you for responding.

Comment: Remove the `typedef int houseClassType`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I got it! It wasn't a typedef issue, or an int issue at all! It was the fact that I didn't have the #include house.h file name at the top of my realtor.h header file. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The C++ language likes to have unique type names throughout a translation module.  The following are not unique type names:

```
class houseClassType  
typedef int houseClassType;
```

If you **must** use the same name, then you'll need to use `namespaces` to separate them:

```
namespace City
{
  class houseClassType;
}
namespace Suburban
{
  typedef int houseClassType;
}
struct realtorStructType
{
  Suburban::houseClassType homes[MAX_HOMES];
};
```

I highly recommend you draw or design this issue first.  This will help you with names too.

The simple solution is to use different names.

Also, do you need the suffix "ClassType" or "StructType" in your name?  In a good design, whether it be a struct or class doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ambiguous.  If you have

```
class houseClassType;
typedef int houseClassType;
```

What would the following code mean?

```
houseClassType x = new houseClassType();
```

You can resolve the ambiguity using a `namespace`, but it's better to change your second `houseClassType` type and name.

An example might look like this.

```
class House {

  public:

    enum class Type {
      ...
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It appears the issue had nothing to do with type defs or int datatypes. I was strictly supposed to set the homes array to a dataType houseClassType. I kept getting the error because I didn't have the #include house.h file name at the top of my realtor.h header file. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @Smiter Are you sure?  The code you submitted above shouldn't be accepted by a valid compiler.  You still need to fix your ambiguity issue.

Comment: I removed the line that said "typedef int houseClassType;" and added "#include house.h" at the top of the realtor.h header file. But now that you mention it, I am having a c2019 error when I compile my program in the main.

Comment: @Smiter Submit a new question if you need to.  Try reading [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before you submit it.

Comment: OK I submitted my new query. I get the feeling Stack Overflow is going to be my new best friend. As well as everybody on it. Thanks again!